# How to return 2 collections while filtering using Collections2?

Tags: collections, filter, guava

Let's say we have a `predicateA` which we want to apply on `ParentList`, so that the list which actually satisfies `predicateA` is `ListA` which is a sublist of `ParentList`. What I am also interested is `ListB` which is `(ParentList - ListA)` which is the remaining list of elements which don't satisfy `PredicateA`.

One way to do it is by applying Negation of PredicateA. For example:-

```
Collections2.filter(ParentList, PredicateA); -> ListA

Collections2.filter(ParentList, Predicates.not(PredicateA)); -> ListB
```

Wouldn't it be possible to extract ListA & ListB into two lists using a single invocation to filter function?

Something like: those that satisfy `PredicateA` is populated in `ListA` and those that doesn't satisfy `PredicateA` is populated in `ListB`.

The reason for asking is performance. I would need to apply `PredicateA` again to the same set of elements in the second invocation shown above.

Is this usecase solved already by Google Guava or similar collections library?

Is there any library doing this currently? or is Google Guava already planned to do it? Is it a good thing to do, so I could write a issue in github for Google Guava?

Comment: You're mistaken. Those two methods don't apply the predicate to anything. They don't produce a subcollection. They just return a live view over the original collection. But you're free to iterate over the original collection, apply the predicate to every element, and store it in one of two Lists, Sets or whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`Multimaps.index(Iterable, Function)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) to index/group/partition your values by some key (in this case by `PredicateA`). You'll then have access to each list of values: one for those elements that satisfy the predicate and another for those that do not.

e.g.:

```java
final ImmutableListMultimap<Boolean, T> index = Multimaps.index(ParentList, PredicateA);
final ImmutableList<T> satisfiedList = index.get(true);
final ImmutableList<T> unsatisfiedList = index.get(false);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out and come back.